# prompt is not taking input in vs code

Tags: javascript, user-input, prompt

I'm unable to take user input in vs code in javascript by using prompt (I know it is made for browser but it works in vs code too). Its not showing any error but when I'm typing something its not taking it as input and I have to terminate the program manually.

I have installed node, I have used "npm install prompt-sync" command in terminal (it installed some json files) , I have defined prompt in program { const prompt = require('prompt-sync)(); } but when I'm using it, It's not showing any error and running program properly but its not accepting any input that I am giving, and I have to manually terminate the program.

```
const prompt = require('prompt-sync');
let age = prompt("enter your age: ");
console.log(age);
```

Comment: I figured it out, I was using "code runner" extension which was creating the problem, when I ran it in terminal without code runner it worked fine.

Comment: And maybe if you require it properly as it is described in the docs , ie `const prompt = require("prompt-sync")(); let age = prompt("your age");` it will really work